# How to connect two android devices and show text from A's clipboard on B's screen - all approaches?

Tags: android, bluetooth, messaging

Basically - the task:

On device one, text is copied to clipboard.

Device two must perform some actions with the text just copied on device one, for example invoke a browser with search engine page and query ?q=text-from-clipboard-just-copied-on-device-A.

*First question*: is it possible to do with out-of-the box applications?

*Second question*: if not, what are different approaches to do that?

Both devices are on the same local wi-fi network (connected via router). Connection via external ip server is not what I want, I would prefer a server running on device A or device B (android) if there's any, so there would be not need in working internet connection.

- I see there's an option of Wi-fi direct (my devices are 4.0 and 4.2 Android versions, so it's possible). Is there a source code how to send a message with wifi direct and receive it on the other side?

Comment: Maybe there's open Android app source code to change "action" activity and keep server-client functionality? That would be almost out-of-the box.

Comment: *Except for Chatbox demo :)

Answer (score 1):

First question: is it possible to do with out-of-the box applications?

No it is not possible with out of box applications. I would be surprised if there would be one!

Second question: if not, what are different approaches to do that?

One approach will be to implement Bluetooth Server and Client applications that can communicate between them and excange data. Ofcourse you will be able to implement different functionalities for example opening a webpage with the text as you mentioned in your question.

Or you can also have a look at NFC Communication explained here: (Remember the devices will have to be at very short distances to achieve such communication) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess question 1 is not possible. I can't imagine that an out of the box app knows what action you want to perform with the received data.

Solution for question two could be working with tcp sockets. One device as server one as client, so that you can send your sting, link or whatever to the other device, which receives this and performs some action.

edit: Sorry, just read that you don't want to do it with internet permission, so data exchange via bluetooth, sms... could be possible

Comment: Maybe there's open Android app source code to change "action" activity and keep server-client functionality? That would be almost out-of-the box.

Comment: Well, internet connection is not a problem, the only thing I don't want an external server running somewhere as a layer between 2 Androids.

Comment: If one phone is the server, the other is the client and both devices are in the same network you don't need an external server and nothing should be routed through the internet. Perhaps this will help. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/